# Getting mouse coordinates in Haskell FLTK

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to load an image into a fltkhs box widget and do some image processing on it and I'd like to get the coordinates when the mouse click on a point on the image.

I couldn't find any part of fltkhs that can handle mouse events.
Anyone could give any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glancing through the documentation yielded this page:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fltkhs-0.5.4.1/docs/Graphics-UI-FLTK-LowLevel-FL.html

It has a function with the following signature:

```
getMouse :: IO Position
```

I suppose it's FLTKHS's analogue for get_mouse